# Binding development ssl certificate to an IP address with VS2015 as a local instance

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2015, ssl-certificate, iis-express

I have a development API sitting on my Windows 10 box. The bindings are fine for http for access on different machines on my local network so I can test the any of the API that uses GET. However, if I want to use https, IIS is only binding to localhost (I have the correct IP address:port_number set in the applicationConfig file and also have a binding to localhost:port_number for SSL).

On the project, I've enabled SSL and it initially comes up with the correct IP/port combo (say 192.168.0.6:44315). However, accessing that gives me an invalid certificate warning. It works fine on localhost, but that is not accessible outside of the machine.

Is there a way to add the certificate to the correct IP/port combination for use when deploying through VS2015 as a local instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is IIS Express who by default forces all site bindings to be localhost.

If you do want to open it up for external access, you have to modify IIS Express configuration file as well as HTTP driver certificate mapping.

Scott Hanselman has a blog post covering that,

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Comment: We made a free VS Extension called Conveyor that does this without the config changed: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti